# Create histogram with custom frequency values

Tags: python, plot, histogram

I want to create a histogram plot with already known values of the frequency. The histogram is like - [histogram plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGPq4.png). I can find the required 'number density'/y-axis values using web plot digitiser and now want to recreate this plot with the correct y-axis values of the number density of each particular bin. I have looked up tutorials of matplotlib and other related questions but it does not seem like it can be done with it. Any help/resource regarding this would be helpful, assuming if it is possible in python or even another language.

Edit - The output I am expecting should be somewhat like this (I know its quite crude) - [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEpiC.png)

The data I want to plot as a histogram could be assumed to be like -

4.2 nm to 4.3 nm - 0%(no values in this range)

4.3 nm to 4.4 nm - 33%

4.4 nm to 4.5 nm - 40%

Comment: could you provide some data, code and expected output?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I haven't got code because I don't know where to start.

Comment: but your date is already percentages in each bin or you need to calculate those percentages? Could you include an example of your input data?

Comment: @Sembei Norimaki I have all the data already, both the bins and their required y-value/frequency. I am just trying to plot this manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you already have a list with the percentages in each bin and the bin centers

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
binCenters = [4.2, 4.3, 4.4]
percentages = [0, 33, 40]
plt.bar(binCenters, percentages)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can work with this!